# Default option in MVC DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want a select HTML element on my page to display the choice of billers for making a payment. In addition to the options for billers I want to display a default option `"Select"` in the select element. I am using `DropDownListFor` of Html helper as given below:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BillerId, new SelectList(Model.Billers,
                   "BillerId", "BillerName", "Select"), new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.BillerId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

The HTML output I get is as given below:

```
<select class="form-control valid" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field BillerId must be a number." id="BillerId" name="BillerId">
    <option value="1">Idea</option>
    <option value="2">Airtel</option>
</select>
```

The default value Select is not showing up. Please let me know if I am mistaking anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a string parameter after `selectList` called `optionLabel` like following.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BillerId, new SelectList(Model.Billers,
                   "BillerId", "BillerName"), "Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 2):

From your question, the `)` is in the wrong spot.

What you have:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BillerId, new SelectList(Model.Billers,
               "BillerId", "BillerName", "Select"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

What it needs to be:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BillerId, new SelectList(Model.Billers,
               "BillerId", "BillerName"),"Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

This will place the `"Select"` string in the correct position in relation to the overloaded `DropDownListFor` method.. specifically the `optionLabel` parameter.

I hope this helps!